# Build.grad does not load the 'index.js' Bundle when emulated on Android 9

Tags: react-native

I created my app and there is a login feature for each user to have their own profile. When I test emulating the app in androids versions 6, 7.1, 8.1, it installs normally and when it arrives in the login part, the application recognizes the user / password and logs in.

But when I emulate on Android 9, something wrong happens. After typing user / password, it does not load the next page and I realize that my 'index.js' Bundle does not load when starting the react-native run-android command.

How can I solve?

Windows 10, React Native latest version, MongoDB.

Login Code:

```
loginUser() {
    login(this.state)
      .then(response => {
        if (response) {
          const aux = response.data;
          aux.jwt = response.token;
          this.props.updateALL(aux);
          Actions.main();
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ alertMessage: error.message, showIcon: true });
      });   }
```

Package.JSON

```
{
  "name": "ifun",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.395.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "date-diff": "^0.2.1",
    "fuctbase64": "^1.4.0",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.2",
    "install": "^0.12.2",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-carousel-view": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.2",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-mime-types": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.45.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "23.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Build.Gradle App

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ifun"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true 
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

when I emulate on Android 9, something wrong happens. After typing user / password, it does not load the next page and I realize that my 'index.js' Bundle does not load when starting the react-native run-android command.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your existing apps work correctly on the new version of the platform. This step does not use new APIs or change the app's `targetSdkVersion`, but it may require minor changes.

can you try low `TargetSdkVersion`?

If this is resolved, please refer to [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28?hl=en) for more information.